# Electron - Messages from Main to Renderer result in empty object

Tags: javascript, json, electron, ipc

I have an Electron application that sends file metadata as an object from the Main process to the Renderer process via IPC (using Electron's built in `ipcRenderer.send()`).

My issue is when sending this metadata, there is a property that is a `Set` object that becomes a blank object. In my `toJSON()` method for the file metadata, it converts the `Set` to an array like so:

```
toJSON() {
    let copy = Object.assign({}, this);
    copy.tags = Array.from(copy.tags);
    return copy;
}
```

While stepping through both the main and renderer processes in the debugger, Electron never seems to call the `toJSON()` method (though it is called when we serialize the metadata object elsewhere).

I assume the `Set` is becoming a blank object during serialization, but why is Electron not calling `toJSON()` before sending the data over IPC? And how can I have it properly convert the object?

EDIT: Let me provide a better explanation and example. See below

Here is the function that is called in the front-end renderer process:

```
function getFile(...args) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let result = ipcRenderer.sendSync('getFile', ...args);
        resolve(result);
    });
}
```

Here is the code in the Main process that responds to that message:

```
ipcMain.on('getFile', async (event, ...args) => {
    let result = await myGetFileFunc(...args); // myGetFileFunc returns an instance of File()

    event.returnValue = result || false;
});
```

Here is the `File` class, which `myGetFileFunc` returns an instance of:

```
class File() }

    constructor() {
        this.tags = new Set();
    }

    getTags() {
        return this.tags;
    }

    setTags(tags) {
        this.tags = tags;
    }

    prepareForJSON() {
        let copy = Object.assign({}, this);
        copy.tags = Array.from(copy.tags);

        return copy;
    }
}
```

And finally, here's the `Tag` class:

```
class Tag {
    constructor(id, name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    toJSON() {
        return {
            id: this.id,
            name: this.name
        };
    }
```

In summary, the renderer process calls `ipcRenderer.send()`, the Main process responds with the file object, which includes a `Set` of `Tag`s, but upon receiving the file object in the renderer process, the `Set` with `Tag`s in it becomes an empty object, `{}`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While your question describes your issue pretty well, please make sure to include a [mcve] so that we can replicate the behaviour and help you faster. How are you sending the object? (And why do you expect Electron to auto-serialise your object? [Both](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-renderer) [docs](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-main) do not say anything about that...)

Comment: It's likely that you're doing this, but could you clarify that you're putting `toJSON` on the `prototype` of `Set`?

Comment: Or I guess it wouldn't be on `Set`, but on your file metadata class.

Comment: Yes that's correct. The toJSON method I showed above is in my file metadata class. I will update with more details tomorrow.